# How do I use SIFT in OpenCV 3.0 with c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, opencv3.0

I have OpenCV 3.0, and I have compiled & installed it with the opencv_contrib module so that's not a problem. Unfortunately the examples from previous versions do not work with the current one, and so although this question has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652812/sift-implementation-in-opencv-2-4-6-ubuntu) [more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297706/using-opencv-to-implement-sift-in-image) I would like a more current example that I can actually work with. Even the [official examples](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html#table-of-content-feature2d) don't work in this version (feature detection works but not other feature examples) and they use SURF anyway.

So, how do I use OpenCV SIFT on C++? I want to grab the keypoints in two images and match them, similar to [this example](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher), but even just getting the points and descriptors would be enough help. Help!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. get the [opencv_contrib repo](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/)
2. take your time with the readme there, add it to your *main* opencv cmake settings
3. rerun cmake /make / install in the main opencv repo

then:

```
   #include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"

  // 
  // now, you can no more create an instance on the 'stack', like in the tutorial
  // (yea, noticed for a fix/pr).
  // you will have to use cv::Ptr all the way down:
  //
  cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
  //cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
  //cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = ORB::create();
  // you get the picture, i hope..

  //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints:
  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;    
  f2d->detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
  f2d->detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );

  //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)    
  Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;    
  f2d->compute( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
  f2d->compute( img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

  //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using BFMatcher :
  BFMatcher matcher;
  std::vector< DMatch > matches;
  matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );
```

also, don't forget to link opencv_xfeatures2d !

Comment: In the documentation detect and compute only appears as python functions. Is the documentation incomplete? Is the SIFT class better documented anywhere? And is the SIFT::operator() unusable or am I just doing something horribly wrong? Edit: the create(...) function isn't anywhere that I've looked in the online documentation... I guess I'm either looking in all the wrong places or I'm just going to have to do without the dox.

Comment: operator() is still there, but using that from a pointer, would make it something like f2d->operator(...). better use: f2d->detectAndCompute(...) then. (and yea, the docs *need* a fix urgently...)

Comment: The edit helps. After a bit of research I'd like to add that you can also use `detectAndCompute(img, mask, keypoints, descriptors)` and that you can use `noArray()` on that if you don't want a mask.

Comment: Also for future reference, you can use [drawMatches()](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html?highlight=drawmatches#drawmatches) to actually see the matches.

Comment: @berak How do you link opencv_xfeature2d?

Answer (score 4):

There are useful answers, but I'll add my version (**for OpenCV 3.X**) just in case the above ones aren't clear (tested and tried):

1. Clone opencv from https://github.com/opencv/opencv to home dir
2. Clone opencv_contrib from https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib to home dir
3. Inside opencv, create a folder named `build`
4. Use this CMake command, to activate non-free modules: `cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/YOURUSERNAME/opencv_contrib/modules -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE:BOOL=ON ..` (**Please notice that we showed where the contrib modules resides and also activated the nonfree modules**)
5. Do `make` and `make install` afterwards

The above steps should work out for OpenCV 3.X

After that, you may run the below code using g++ with the appropriate flags:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -lutil -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lopencv_xfeatures2d -o surftestexecutable
```

The important thing not to forget is to link the xfeatures2D library with **-lopencv_xfeatures2d** as shown on the command. And the `main.cpp` file is:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    const cv::Mat input = cv::imread("surf_test_input_image.png", 0); //Load as grayscale

    Ptr< cv::xfeatures2d::SURF> surf =  xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    surf->detect(input, keypoints);

    // Add results to image and save.
    cv::Mat output;
    cv::drawKeypoints(input, keypoints, output);
    cv::imwrite("surf_result.jpg", output);


    return 0;
}
```

This should create and save an image with surf keypoints.