# Is surf descriptor extractor still available in opencv3.1?

Tags: descriptor, extractor, opencv3.1

Does anybody know if surfdescriptorextractor is still available in opencv 3.1? if it is how may i use it can you direct me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use SIFT in OpenCV 3.0 with c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533203/how-do-i-use-sift-in-opencv-3-0-with-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not included by default after Opencv 3.0, now this is in opencv_contrib at xfeatures2d module. You will need to compile with the contrib module.

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src

Look for a similar question

[How do I use SIFT in OpenCV 3.0 with c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533203/how-do-i-use-sift-in-opencv-3-0-with-c)